# Authorization fails with Error 403 randomly for Google API Client for Google BigQuery Call when making multiple calls per second

Tags: google-bigquery, google-api-client

I've seeing 403 RANDOMLY (works some times and fails the other times) while trying to authorize with Google API Client to make Google Big Query calls.

To provide more context, I'm making several api calls together 5-10 per second so when I make the calls sequentially, I don't get the error. However when I make several calls per second, I get the error. I checked the BigQuery Rate Limit here: https://developers.google.com/bigquery/quota-policy
and it says I can issue upto 20 concurrent queries. I'm pretty sure, I'm not at the rate limit.

I'll appreciate any pointers or suggestions to address this systematically.
Thanks,
Navneet

Here's the code:

```
    def initialize
     client = Google::APIClient.new
     path_to_key_file = "/Users/abcyoo/crazy/crazy-google-client-key.p12" #dev
     passphrase = "XXXXXXXX"
     key = Google::APIClient::PKCS12.load_key(path_to_key_file, passphrase)
     service_account = Google::APIClient::JWTAsserter.new(
         '1063766308008@developer.gserviceaccount.com',
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery',
         key)
         client.authorization = service_account.authorize
     client.authorization.fetch_access_token!
     bq = client.discovered_api("bigquery", "v2")
     return client,bq
   end
```

Here's the error message I receive:

```
    Signet::AuthorizationError (Authorization failed.  Server message:
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"><html><head><title>Google Accounts</title><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" /><link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='https://ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/o/1893590695-error_page_css_ltr.css'>
```

**403.** That's an error.

You are not authorized to perform this request.  That's all we know.):

```
    signet (0.4.5) lib/signet/oauth_2/client.rb:875:in `fetch_access_token'
    signet (0.4.5) lib/signet/oauth_2/client.rb:888:in `fetch_access_token!'
     app/controllers/application_controller.rb:105:in `initialize'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you calling client.discoverty_api 5-10 times per second? If so, that may be what is rate limiting you. Can you call this once or once per thread and reuse the bigquery service?

Comment: Thanks Jordan. That was the issue. Appreciate your quick help